# Tags related to languages

Tags: discussion, tags, languages

I have seen a user tag a question with [swedish](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/swedish), and there may be other languages. Should such tags be avoided, instead using [language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language), [language-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language-support) or [localization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/localization)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they needed to be merged, likely in to either localization or language.

Comment: Sorry about this. I'm the one responsible for tagging a question [tag:swedish] (thus creating that tag).