# Are language specific tags needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags related to languages](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3919/tags-related-to-languages)

It has came to my notice that there are some language / country specific tags floating around (actually, there are a lot of posts using them).

[chinese](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/chinese), [japanese](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/japanese), [korean](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/korean) are the 3 quickest examples I can find.

To my idea tags should point to a specific subject, concise and consistent (not ambiguous) and useful so that the people following them can easily find related posts and help or be helped.

I would say those tags are useless and the posts created with them should be covered by the [internationalization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) tag with some other that better focuses the issue, ie: [fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fonts), [ibus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ibus), [keyboard-layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-layout), etc.

Should we keep those and allow them to exist or clean them? Why? Who are they helping there?